# Combining several tables of different types with common columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a database that has 6 different user types (web_users, sellers, repair_centers,...) they all have common options (columns) that will be used a lot, but each of the have some unique columns that other user types don't have.

Now I want to know is it wise to create just one user table with common columns and use another table as options table for those unique columns or should I create a separate table for each user type?

EDIT: actually all different types of will have same functionality in website. the differences are like sellers can have a logo that web_users can't. producers have Producer_ID (that is defined by government) that others don't have, and .... 
and all those unique columns are fixed values that no operations done on them.

Comment: It's wise if it makes it easier to perform the majority of operations you need to perform on those tables. These options are patterns called  [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) and  [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html). It's your call to decide which one to use, based on the functionality you need to support. EDIT: there's also a third related pattern called [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)

Comment: @w0lf I have edited my question, can you please have look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting question. If it were me, I'd use two tables: one for all the common properties and another for all the outlying properties of the users. Something like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE _UserProperties(
    ID int ,
    Property varchar(1000) ,
    Value varchar(1000) ,
    UserID int 
  ) ;
  insert into _UserProperties(id, property, value, userid)
  values (1,'employee id', '123556',1),
        (2,'CustomerID', '345677',2),
        (2,'SalesGroup', 'ABFD34',2),
        (2,'SalesToDate', '2344',2),
        (3,'Project', 'cat juggling',3);


  CREATE TABLE _Users(
    ID int ,
    UserName varchar(50) ,
    UserAddress varchar(1000) ,
    UserType varchar(50) 
  ) ;      

  insert into _Users (ID, UserName, UserAddress, UserType)
  values (1,'Fred Jones','123 Mample','Customer'),
        (2,'Sam Smith','234 Oak','Employee'),
        (3,'Sally Black','345 Pine','Consultant');
```

Then you can combine everything with a simple query like:

```
 select * from _users a left join _userProperties b
 on a.id = b.userid
```

or use a pivot table to make the rows in to columns.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle View](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e783b/1)

Comment: yes, I exactly had this on mind, but was not sure whether to use it like this or to separate the tables

Comment: I think breaking every data element down to its own table makes the programming easier in the long run, but if it's reporting you're after or quickness in delivering the solution, fewer tables can help.